# How do you stream data into partitioned tables in bigquery?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We're streaming data into BigQuery with Firebase and BigQuery has automatically set up the events table into date-sharded tables, creating a new table for every day. I want to stream every day into one table and partition on event_date. Any ideas as to how I can implement this?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions: _"Partition decorators enable you to write the query results to a specific partition. To adjust for timezones, use a partition decorator to write data to a partition based on your preferred timezone"_ (`[TABLE]$[PARTITION]`)

Comment: Your comment is good, could you post it as an answer so it gets more visibility?Also consider this document: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaming_into_ingestion-time_partitioned_tables